# Get image based on song playing in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am building a flutter music app and I want to retrieve album cover from the internet based on the song playing. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes there is a way

Comment: @TSR can you tell me how?

Comment: I would check out the spotify api